# Brace expression does not work in find regex

Tags: find, regular-expression

I have two folders, `CA01` and `CA02` under current folder, `foo`:

```
foo -+
     |
     +-CA01
     |
     +-CA02
```

When I type

```
find . -regex ".*CA[0-9]+" -exec echo {} +
```

Or

```
find . -regex ".*CA[0-9][0-9]" -exec echo {} +
```

I have the following output, which is expected:

```
./CA01 ./CA02
```

But when I type in

```
find . -regex ".*CA[0-9]\{2\}" -exec echo {} +
```

**Nothing shows up, which is quite unexpected.**

Because, by default, `find` uses emacs regex.  I could use all the above to match the two folders.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `-regextype` to one that supports repetition counts (i.e. `{2}`). The default one, `emacs` doesn't appear to support the counts. The default regex type imitates an older version of Emacs that didn't have a syntax for repetition counts. The types below appear to work for me.

#### Examples

*posix-egrep*

```
$ find foo -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*CA[0-9]{2}" -exec echo {} +
foo/CA02 foo/CA01
```

*sed*

```
$ find foo -regextype sed -regex ".*CA[0-9]\{2\}" -exec echo {} +
foo/CA02 foo/CA01
```

*posix-extended*

```
$ find foo -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*CA[0-9]{2}" -exec echo {} +
foo/CA02 foo/CA01
```

There are others but I didn't try any more. See the `find` man page and search for `-regextype`.

*excerpt*

```
-regextype type
       Changes  the  regular  expression  syntax  understood by -regex and 
       -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently
       implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, 
       posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

#### My version of find

```
$ find -version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.9
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version 1778ee9e7d0e150a37db66a0e51c1a56755aab4f
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Comment: It seems true that the default does not support the count.  BTW, did you update your `find` manually?  My find version is only `4.4.2' on ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @gongzhitaao - I'm on Fedora 14. That's the version that's stock with it.

Comment: A little gotcha that might trip some people up: the `-regextype` switch must be entered /before/ the `-regex` one, or else it won't take effect.